# Mi Onchange de JQuery no funciona bien

Tags: php, jquery

Hola es que me he topado con un problema, al formar mi onchange para filtrar 2 select uno si lo filtra y el otro me arroja una A pero es por que no manda la variable, a pesar de que si tiene bien los ID no se que es lo que falte

```
introducir el código aquí
// Este si funciona
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#num_objeto").change(function () {
                $("#num_objeto option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_obj = $(this).val();
                    $.post("php/Obtener_Combos.php", {
                        id_obj: id_obj
                    }, function (data) {
                        $("#id_situacion").html(data);
                    })
                })
            })
        });
// este ya no :c 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#id_situacion").change(function () {
              $("#id_situacion option:selected").each(function () {
                   id_sit = $(this).val();
                $.post("php/Obtener_Combos.php",{Etapa:id_sit},function (data) {
                  $("#id_etapas_select").html(data);
                })
              })
            })
        });
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el HTML de tu código? Por otra parte, no necesitas dos bloques `$(document).ready(function () {`, lo propio sería un solo bloque y dentro de él todas las demás funciones que trabajarán dentro del DOM.

Comment: ya lo puse abajo como sugieres hacer la funcion ?

Comment: prueba comentar el primer bloque que tienes donde dice que te funciona solo por probar, esa parte va a dejar de funcionar pero realiza la prueba con la parte que no te funciona a ver si así si te logra funcionar. Si ese es el caso, solo sería hacer lo que proponen en el primer comentario, así se te brinda una solución mas eficaz. si no ps ya se revisa mas a fondo

Comment: Usa la parte de la misma pregunta, pulsando en [edit], para agregar el código que falta. La parte de abajo es sólo para respuestas. Los ids de los elementos parecen correctos, ¿a qué te refieres con que te muestra sólo una `A`? ¿Has revisado la consola? ¿Acaso lo que no funciona no será la petición Ajax del segundo onchange? Prueba a poner un `alert` en ese segundo bloque para ir depurando cosas.

Comment: eh revisado la consola pero no marca errores lo que marca es que no ha detectado ninguna variable de el "id_situacion" no esta mandando nada pero si llega a Obtener_Combos.php, la cuestion es que no manda lo que le pido al onchange intente hacerlo en una sola funcion pero sigue igual....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es correcto usar dos bloques `$(document).ready(function() {`, porque el propósito del mismo es esperar que el DOM (`document`) esté listo. En ese contexto el DOM es uno, no son dos DOM. Significa que deberías poner dentro del listener todas las funciones que quieras lanzar cuando el mismo esté listo.

Te pongo un ejemplo de tus dos `select` dentro de un único bloque de escucha del DOM. Intenta así, si no funciona, será por otro motivo ajeno a esto. En los log de consola podrás ver que ambos funcionan.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*
    Listener de num_objeto
  */
  $("#num_objeto").change(function() {
    $("#num_objeto option:selected").each(function() {
      id_obj = $(this).val();
      console.log(id_obj);
      $.post("php/Obtener_Combos.php", {
        id_obj: id_obj
      }, function(data) {
        $("#id_situacion").html(data);
      })
    })
  })
  
  /*
    Listener de id_situacion
  */
  $("#id_situacion").change(function() {
    $("#id_situacion option:selected").each(function() {
      id_sit = $(this).val();
      console.log(id_sit);

      $.post("php/Obtener_Combos.php", {
        Etapa: id_sit
      }, function(data) {
        $("#id_etapas_select").html(data);
      })
    })
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="num_objeto">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>--num objeto--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="id_situacion">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>--id situacion--</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: si funcionan pero igual me sigue arrojando un error, puede que tengas razon y sea por un motivo ajeno, la verdad me saca mucho de onda, ya lo habia intentado dentro de la misma funcion como habian mencionado

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi HTML

introducir el código aquí

```
                <div class="container pt-4">
                    <form method="POST">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="inputState" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Seleccionar Objeto:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="custom-select line" id="num_objeto" name="num_objeto">
                                    <option value='0'>Seleccionar Situacion</option>
                                    <?php
                        include_once 'php/Consultaclientes.php';
                        $consulta = new Consultaclientes();
                        $rows_Objeto = $consulta->Consulta_Objeto1();
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows_Objeto); $i++) {
                     echo "<option value='" . $rows_Objeto[$i]["id_objeto"] . "'>" . $rows_Objeto[$i]["Objeto"] . "</option>";
                          }
             ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="inputState" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Situación Asociada:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="custom-select line" id="id_situacion" name="id_situacion">
                                    <option value='0'>Seleccionar Situacion</option>


                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="inputState" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Etapa Asociada:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="custom-select line" id="id_etapas_select" name="id_etapas_select">
                                    <option value='0'>Seleccionar etapa</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="inputState" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fecha Oficio/Tramite :</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha_doc_inte" name="fecha_doc_inte"
                                    placeholder="Fecha">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">

                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <button class="btn btn-dark btn_sat_black text-white btn-lg"
                                    type="submit">Aceptar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```